# Jetty runner is not executing the war file

Tags: jetty

I have a project named as test using spring,hibernate and struts.It is running when am using eclipse.But when i export this project as war and execute it using jetty runner in command prompt it just extracted the project and listed the contents in the browser.But i want the project to be executed.I have tried with some other simple web application war using the same procedure and it works fine.But in my project its not working with jetty.

here is my code for jetty

```
D:\>java -jar jetty-runner-7.0.0.v20091005.jar test.war

i just listing some console output of jetty

INFO::RUNNER 
NO tx manager found
deploying file:D:/test.war @/[webAppContext@86f241@86f241/,null,file:D:/test.war
```

can any one tell me a solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

1) use a newer version of runner, 7.6.3.v20120416

2) what context are you trying to navigate to, you might want to experiment with some of the other cli options on the runner to set the context and whatnot from the command line and experiment with that.  [This site](http://webtide.intalio.com/2008/04/jetty-runner/) has some good information on using this artifact as well.